# Hack for using hardware to take square roots of 128 bit numbers

Tags: floating-point

I need to take integer square roots $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ of (lots of) 128 bit numbers $n$. Calling gmp seems to take surprisingly long (though I can't tell for sure, since gmp routines are not showing up in the profiler information).

Is there a standard way to compute $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ in this situation using hardware (to the extent possible)?

The best I can think of is reducing the problem to that for 64-bit by means of a single application of the algorithm in https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072854/en/ (that is, that algorithm minus recursion; it's basically just a single Newton iteration) and then computing $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ using the `sqrtl` function in a system (say, gcc running on 64-bit x86 systems) where `long double` obeys the standard for 80-bit extended precision. Or is `sqrtl` not guaranteed to give a correctly rounded value for $\sqrt{n}$, or at least a valid rounded value (that is, $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ or $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor+1$)?

Comment: Are your 128 bit numbers integers or floats? What gmp function are you using to compute the square roots?

Comment: My 128 bit numbers are integers. I'm using gmp's sqrt function (for integers, in the C++ interface).

Comment: If your architecture supports `__int128`, perhaps you can write a function for sqrt using Karatsuba's method. This data type is fixed-width, and should be much faster than `mpz_t`. 

Click here to descend into a rabbit hole on integer square roots of big numbers!

https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/413l1u/an_optimization_story_switching_from_gmp_to_gccs/

Comment: What I have done is combine a single iteration of the Karatsuba-Zimmerman method (which, at least at first sight, is basically just Newton's method in integer arithmetic, with a clever use of powers of 2) with one call to extended-precision sqrt (implemented in hardware I suppose).

Comment: @HAHelfgott Does the code have to be portable? Does your system platform support 128/64->64 bit unsigned integer division, like the `DIV` instruction on x86_64 CPUs? If so, a lazy way to do this is to use a small table for a starting approximation followed by three applications of Heron's Method which has quadratic convergence. Most of the computational cost would be three division instructions, for a total of around 300 clock cycles for the square root.

Comment: @njuffa The code doesn't have to be portable - but then I can assume sqrt is implemented on hardware for extended-precision floats, as it is on x86_64 CPUs, isn't it?

Comment: @HAHelfgott As far as I know the old x87 FPU is still there, but I am not sure how it is accessible from a 64-bit environment (I have been focusing on the SIMD instruction sets for the past 20 years). You might as well use a double-precision AVX-based square root as the starting point. Caveats may apply for in the conversions between floating-point and integers due to rounding, so careful testing will be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my (Saturday-afternoon, both literally and figuratively) code. No claims of elegance or optimality made - please shoot! You will see main() takes $10^9$ square roots using the hybrid Zimmermann(-Karatsuba(-Newton))/hardware procedure I proposed, and also takes them using gmp; it also checks that the two methods give the same answer in all tested (pseudorandom) . It would seem my hybrid procedure is a little over 8.5 times faster.

I'm sure one can do better than my code below. Oh yes, of course it's non-portable (it's meant for gcc running on x86-64) but let's not worry about that for now. Note I am not assuming anything on whether the FPU rounds upwards, downwards or to the nearest representable number.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef unsigned __int128 I;

#define LOG2(X) ((unsigned) (8*sizeof(ulong) - 1 - __builtin_clzl((X))))
/* log2 rounded down; works only in gcc */


inline long log2l(I x)
{
 ulong high, low;

 high = x>>64;
 if(high)
   return LOG2(high)+64;
 else {
  low = x&(~((ulong) 0));
  return LOG2(x);
 }
}

ulong sqrt128(I n)
/* returns floor of sqrt(n) */
/* works for 0<=n<2^{125} */
{
 int flag=0, k, be;
 ulong head, q, a1, num, den, s,sp,sp2,rp;
 I r;

 k = log2l(n); be=k/4+1;
 if((k%4)<2) {
   flag = 1;
   n <<= 2;
 }
 head = n>>(2*be);
 a1 = n - (head<<(2*be));
 a1 >>= be;

 sp = sqrtl(head); sp2 = sp*sp;
 if(head>sp2)
   rp = head-sp2;
 else {
   rp=(head+2*sp-1)-sp2;
   sp--;
 }

 /* So: sp = integer part of sqrt(head), rp = head-sp*sp */
 num = ((rp<<be)+a1); den = 2*sp;
 q = num/den;
 s = (sp<<be) + q;

 if(((I) s)*((I) s) > n)
   s--;

 if(flag) 
   s >>= 1;

 return s;
}

const I twop32 = ((I) 4294967296)*((I) 4294967296);
inline mpz_class mpzify(I x)
{
  mpz_class twp32 = ((mpz_class) 4294967296)*((mpz_class) 4294967296);

  return mpz_class((ulong) (x/twop32))*twp32+mpz_class((ulong) (x%twop32));
}

main()
{
  ulong A0,A1,A2,A3,i,j,B;
  I n;
  time_t t0,t1,t2,t3;
  mpz_class Qz;

  t0 = time(NULL);

  srand48(t0);
  for(i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    A0 = lrand48(); A1 = lrand48();
    A2 = lrand48(); A3 = lrand48()>>3;
    n = (((I) (A2 + (A3<<32)))<<64) + A0 + (A1<<32);
    for(j=0; j<1000; j++)
      B =  sqrt128(n+j);
  }
  t1 = time(NULL);
  printf("Wall time for homebrewed sqrt: %ld\n",t1-t0);

  srand48(t0);
  for(i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    A0 = lrand48(); A1 = lrand48();
    A2 = lrand48(); A3 = lrand48()>>3;
    n = (((I) (A2 + (A3<<32)))<<64) + A0 + (A1<<32);
    for(j=0; j<1000; j++) {
      Qz =  sqrt(mpzify(n+j));
      B = Qz.get_ui();
  }
  t2 = time(NULL);
  printf("Wall time for gmp sqrt: %ld\n",t2-t1);

  srand48(t0);
  for(i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    A0 = lrand48(); A1 = lrand48();
    A2 = lrand48(); A3 = lrand48()>>3;
    n = (((I) (A2 + (A3<<32)))<<64) + A0 + (A1<<32);
    for(j=0; j<1000; j++)
      B=A0;
  }
  t3=time(NULL);
  printf("Wall time just for looping: %ld\n",t3-t2);

  printf("Checking that the two algorithms always give the same result...\n");
  srand48(t0);
  for(i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    A0 = lrand48(); A1 = lrand48();
    A2 = lrand48(); A3 = lrand48()>>3;
    n = (((I) (A2 + (A3<<32)))<<64) + A0 + (A1<<32);
    for(j=0; j<1000; j++) {
      Qz =  sqrt(mpzify(n+j));
      B = Qz.get_ui();
      if(B!=sqrt128(n+j))
        printf("Unfortunately not! %lu %lu\n",B,sqrt128(n+j));
    }
  }
  printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Comment: Just a minor note, this will generate a division by zero if n < 8. But as far as I can tell, this won't happen if n >= 8.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with measurements of the execution time of `gmp`'s square root to establish baseline performance. Some of the foremost algorithmic and performance optimization specialists in the world have contributed to `gmp`, which is a mature library. Generally I would be wary of trying to compete with such a library. In fact, the Karatsuba square root algorithm by Paul Zimmermann described in the [paper](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072854/en/) linked by OP is exactly what is used by the square root implementation in `gmp` according to its [online documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Square-Root-Algorithm). Furthermore this algorithm has proven correctness:

Yves Bertot, Nicolas Magaud and Paul Zimmermann, “A Proof of GMP Square Root”, *Journal of Automated Reasoning*, Vol. 29, No. 3-4, September 2002, pp. 225-252 ([manuscript online](https://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/21/13/PDF/RR-4475.pdf))

I don't have `gmp` installed to time the square root myself. Given its general nature as an arbitrary-precision library, it is possible that `gmp` has significant overhead for relatively short operands. Execution times beyond a few hundred cycles on x86_64 hardware would be an indication of that and provide an incentive to attempt a home-brew version.

Since OP specifically asked for "hacks", I did a quick experiment hacking code for a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31149161/780717) regarding a 32-bit integer square root into a 128-bit version. On my Intel Xeon E3 1270v2 (Ivy Bridge), with code compiled with the Intel C compiler version 13.1.3.198 at full optimization, I measure an execution time of about 440 cycles. Since both processors and compilers have advanced in the past 7 years, this should undoubtedly provide an *upper* limit of achievable execution times.

Where a tool chain offers a native 128-bit integer type, that should be used instead of my 128-bit emulation. Also, a much better starting approximation could be used, reducing the number of Newton iterations required for full accuracy. In terms of missed micro optimizations, I had trouble with the inline assembly used to access the `x86_64` instructions `mul` and `div`, in that I could not get `"a"` and `"d"` bindings to work to put operands directly into the `rax` and `rdx` registers used by those.

In standard math library practice, square roots are typically computed via Newton-Raphson (quadratic convergence) or Halley iterations (cubic convergence) of the reciprocal square root as these iterations are division-free, requiring only multiplication. However, crafting such an implementation in a robust fashion would take more time than I can afford to invest in an answer at this time.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MODE_INCR   (1)
#define MODE_DECR   (2)
#define MODE_RANDOM (3)

#define TEST_MODE   (MODE_RANDOM)
#define BENCHMARK   (0)

typedef struct {
    uint64_t lo;
    uint64_t hi;
} my_uint128_t;

/* lookup table for low-accuracy sqrt approximation */
const uint64_t sqrt_tab[32] = 
{ 0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000000000000000ULL, 
  0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000000000000000ULL,
  0x85ffffffffffffffULL, 0x8cffffffffffffffULL, 0x94ffffffffffffffULL, 0x9affffffffffffffULL, 
  0xa1ffffffffffffffULL, 0xa7ffffffffffffffULL, 0xadffffffffffffffULL, 0xb3ffffffffffffffULL,
  0xb9ffffffffffffffULL, 0xbeffffffffffffffULL, 0xc4ffffffffffffffULL, 0xc9ffffffffffffffULL, 
  0xceffffffffffffffULL, 0xd3ffffffffffffffULL, 0xd8ffffffffffffffULL, 0xdcffffffffffffffULL, 
  0xe1ffffffffffffffULL, 0xe6ffffffffffffffULL, 0xeaffffffffffffffULL, 0xeeffffffffffffffULL, 
  0xf3ffffffffffffffULL, 0xf7ffffffffffffffULL, 0xfbffffffffffffffULL, 0xffffffffffffffffULL
};

uint32_t clz_128 (my_uint128_t x);
my_uint128_t shl_128 (my_uint128_t x, uint32_t shift);
uint64_t udiv_128_64 (my_uint128_t x, uint64_t y);
my_uint128_t umul_64_128 (uint64_t a, uint64_t b);
int gt_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y);
uint64_t avg_64 (uint64_t a, uint64_t b);

/* compute integer square root by initial table lookup refined by division-based
   Newton iterations 
*/ 
uint64_t isqrt_128 (my_uint128_t x)
{
    my_uint128_t t;
    uint64_t q, y;
    uint32_t lz, i;

    if ((x.hi | x.lo) == 0) return x.lo; // early out

    // initial guess based on leading 5 bits of normalized argument
    lz = clz_128 (x);
    t = shl_128 (x, (lz & ~1));
    i = t.hi >> (64 - 5);
    y = sqrt_tab[i] >> (lz >> 1);

    // 1st Newton iteration
    q = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
    if (x.hi < y) q = udiv_128_64 (x, y);
    y = avg_64 (y, q);

    if (lz < 106) { // 2nd Newton iteration
        q = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
        if (x.hi < y) q = udiv_128_64 (x, y);
        y = avg_64 (y, q);

        if (lz < 86) { // 3rd Newton iteration
            q = 0xffffffffffffffffULL; 
            if (x.hi < y) q = udiv_128_64 (x, y);
            y = avg_64 (y, q);

            if (lz < 42) { // 4th Newton iteration
                q = 0xffffffffffffffffULL; 
                if (x.hi < y) q = udiv_128_64 (x, y);
                y = avg_64 (y, q);
            }
        }
    }

    if (gt_128 (umul_64_128 (y, y), x)) y--; // adjust quotient if too large

    return y; // (int)sqrt(x)
}

uint32_t clz_128 (my_uint128_t x)
{
    int r = 0;
    if (!(x.lo | x.hi)) return 128;
    if (!(x.hi & 0xffffffffffffffffULL)) { x.hi = x.lo; r += 64; }
    if (!(x.hi & 0xffffffff00000000ULL)) { x.hi <<= 32; r += 32; }
    if (!(x.hi & 0xffff000000000000ULL)) { x.hi <<= 16; r += 16; }
    if (!(x.hi & 0xff00000000000000ULL)) { x.hi <<=  8; r +=  8; }
    if (!(x.hi & 0xf000000000000000ULL)) { x.hi <<=  4; r +=  4; }
    if (!(x.hi & 0xc000000000000000ULL)) { x.hi <<=  2; r +=  2; }
    if (!(x.hi & 0x8000000000000000ULL)) { x.hi <<=  1; r +=  1; }
    return r;
}

my_uint128_t shl_128 (my_uint128_t x, uint32_t shift)
{
    my_uint128_t r;
    if (shift > 127) {
        r.lo = 0ULL;
        r.hi = 0ULL;
    } else if (shift > 63) {
        r.lo = 0ULL;
        r.hi = x.lo << (shift - 64);;
    } else if (shift > 0) {
        r.lo = x.lo << shift;
        r.hi = (x.hi << shift) | (x.lo >> (64 - shift));
    } else {
        r = x;
    }
    return r;
}

/* 128/64->64 bit division. Note: Will overflow if x[127:64] >= y */
uint64_t udiv_128_64 (my_uint128_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    uint64_t quot, rem;
    __asm__ (
        "movq %2, %%rax\n\t"
        "movq %3, %%rdx\n\t"
        "divq %4\n\t"
        "movq %%rax, %0\n\t"
        "movq %%rdx, %1\n\t"
        : "=r" (quot), "=r" (rem)
        : "r" (x.lo), "r" (x.hi), "r" (y)
        : "rax", "rdx");
    return quot;
}

/* 64x64->128 bit multiply */
my_uint128_t umul_64_128 (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    my_uint128_t r;
    __asm__(
        "movq %2, %%rax\n\t"
        "mulq %3\n\t"
        "movq %%rax, %0\n\t"
        "movq %%rdx, %1\n\t"
        : "=r" (r.lo), "=r" (r.hi) 
        : "r" (a), "r" (b) 
        : "rax", "rdx");
    return r;
}

/* macros for multi-word arithmetic */
#define ADDCcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), cy=t0<cy, t0=t0+t1, t1=t0<t1, cy=cy+t1, t0=t0)
#define ADDcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), t0=t0+t1, cy=t0<t1, t0=t0)
#define ADDC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t0+t1)
#define SUBCcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1,t2) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), cy=t0<cy, t2=t1<t0, cy=cy+t2, t1-t0)
#define SUBcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), cy=t1<t0, t1-t0)
#define SUBC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t1-t0)

my_uint128_t add_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    my_uint128_t r;
    uint64_t cy, t0, t1;
    r.lo = ADDcc (x.lo, y.lo, cy, t0, t1);
    r.hi = ADDC (x.hi, y.hi, cy, t0, t1);
    return r;
}

my_uint128_t sub_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    my_uint128_t r;
    uint64_t cy, t0, t1;
    r.lo = SUBcc (x.lo, y.lo, cy, t0, t1);
    r.hi = SUBC (x.hi, y.hi, cy, t0, t1);
    return r;   
}

int gt_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    return (x.hi == y.hi) ? (x.lo > y.lo) : (x.hi > y.hi);
}

int lt_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    return (x.hi == y.hi) ? (x.lo < y.lo) : (x.hi < y.hi);
}

int eq_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    return (x.hi == y.hi) && (x.lo == y.lo);
}

int ge_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    return gt_128 (x, y) || eq_128 (x, y);
}

int le_128 (my_uint128_t x, my_uint128_t y)
{
    return lt_128 (x, y) || eq_128 (x, y);
}

/* compute average of a and b rounded towards zero, preventing overflow */
uint64_t avg_64 (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return (a & b) + ((a ^ b) >> 1);
}

/*
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J
  From: geo <gmars...@gmail.com>
  Newsgroups: sci.math,comp.lang.c,comp.lang.fortran
  Subject: 64-bit KISS RNGs
  Date: Sat, 28 Feb 2009 04:30:48 -0800 (PST)

  This 64-bit KISS RNG has three components, each nearly
  good enough to serve alone.    The components are:
  Multiply-With-Carry (MWC), period (2^121+2^63-1)
  Xorshift (XSH), period 2^64-1
  Congruential (CNG), period 2^64
*/

static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;

#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

static void error_abort (const char * filename, int line, const char *expr)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "\n%s line %d. Assertion failed: %s\n Aborting.\n", 
             filename, line, expr);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define MY_ASSERT(expr)\
    ((expr)?((void)0):((void)error_abort(__FILE__,__LINE__,#expr)))

#if !BENCHMARK
int main (void)
{
    const my_uint128_t zero = {0ULL, 0ULL}, one = {1ULL, 0ULL};
    my_uint128_t x, arg, t;
    uint64_t res;

#if TEST_MODE == MODE_DECR
    printf ("Test integer square root sequentially; decrementing\n");
#elif TEST_MODE == MODE_INCR
    printf ("Test integer square root sequentially; incrementing\n");
#elif TEST_MODE == MODE_RANDOM
    printf ("Test integer square root using purely random argument\n");
#else
#error unsupported TEST_MODE
#endif // TEST_MODE

    x = zero;
    do {
#if TEST_MODE == MODE_RANDOM
        arg.lo = KISS64;
        arg.hi = KISS64 & 0x7fffffffffffffffULL;
#elif TEST_MODE == MODE_DECR
        arg = sub_128 (zero, x);
#elif TEST_MODE == MODE_INCR
        arg = x;
#endif // TEST_MODE
        res = isqrt_128 (arg);
        /* Check correctness: res * res  must be less than or equal to arg.
           (res + 1) * (res + 1) must be greater than arg.
        */
        t.lo = res;
        t.hi = 0ULL;

        MY_ASSERT ((lt_128 (arg, shl_128 (one, 127)) && 
                    le_128 (umul_64_128 (res, res), arg) &&
                    gt_128 (add_128 (add_128 (add_128 (umul_64_128 (res, res), t), t), one), arg))
                   ||
                   (ge_128 (arg, shl_128 (one, 127)) && 
                    le_128 (umul_64_128 (res, res), arg) && 
                    gt_128 (umul_64_128 (res, res), sub_128 (sub_128 (sub_128 (arg, t), t), one)))
);
        if ((x.lo & 0xffffffULL) == 0) printf ("\r%016llx_%016llx", x.hi, x.lo);
        x = add_128 (x, one);
    } while (!(eq_128 (x, zero)));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#else // BENCHMARK

// A routine to give access to a high precision timer on most systems.
#if defined(_WIN32)
#if !defined(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <windows.h>
double second (void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    static double oofreq;
    static int checkedForHighResTimer;
    static BOOL hasHighResTimer;

    if (!checkedForHighResTimer) {
        hasHighResTimer = QueryPerformanceFrequency (&t);
        oofreq = 1.0 / (double)t.QuadPart;
        checkedForHighResTimer = 1;
    }
    if (hasHighResTimer) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter (&t);
        return (double)t.QuadPart * oofreq;
    } else {
        return (double)GetTickCount() * 1.0e-3;
    }
}
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__)
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
double second (void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)tv.tv_sec + (double)tv.tv_usec * 1.0e-6;
}
#else
#error unsupported platform
#endif

#define N 200000000
int main (void)
{
    my_uint128_t x, zero = {0ULL, 0ULL};
    uint64_t r = 0ULL;
    int i, k;
    double start, stop;

    printf ("Running benchmark (%d iterations), please wait ...\n", N);
    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        start = second();
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            x.hi = KISS64;
            x.lo = r ^ x.hi;
            r = isqrt_128 (x);
        }
        stop = second();
    }
    printf ("r=%016llx\n", r);
    printf ("elapsed = %23.16e seconds per isqrt_128\n", (stop-start)/N);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;        
}

#endif // BENCHMARK
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't yet converted your code to use gcc native 128-bit integers for a fair comparison. On gmp: I have just tested gmp sqrt and my homebrew sqrt on my laptop, on 10^9 integers < 2^{125}. gmp takes 191 seconds, while homebrew takes 22. (A second run gives 192 and 21 seconds, respectively.) So using a hybrid of code and hardware would seem to be best (or at least better than gmp).

Comment: ... and yes, I ran a check to make sure the two routines gave the same answers in both cases. Does the sqrt function on x87 processors have proved correctness? (I know it's *supposed* to, in the sense that correct rounding for sqrt is required by the IEEE standard, whereas it is not required for exp, say.)

Comment: See my code below.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Yes, the square root instructions on x86 processors have been proven correct since at least the 1990s. For example, back in those days, I worked on the FPU of the AMD Athlon processor. For proofs for that, see: David Russinoff, "A Mechanically Checked Proof of IEEE Compliance of the Floating Point Multiplication, Division and Square Root Algorithms of the AMD-K7™ Processor", *LMS Journal of Computation and Mathematics* 1 (1998): 148-200. John Harrison was responsible for much of the corresponding work at Intel.

Comment: Good to know! I thought things would have happened a little later. Back in early 1998, I was visiting graduate schools as a prospective student, and I heard of a recent PhD in a leading program who had proved the correctness of addition in the Intel Pentium and, as a result, had become disgusted with life. Or some such thing.

Comment: @HAHelfgott The crucial point in the late 1990s was the introduction of *mechanically checked* proofs for CPU hardware designs. The framework for applying mechanical verifiers to floating-point arithmetic had to be created first, i.e. a lot of groundwork was laid. David Russinoff worked with ACL2 while John Harrison used HOL. As I recall (admittedly my memory is hazy 25 years later) each of the parts covered by Russinoff's paper took several months to complete.